# The "recently imported questions" link has the wrong target

Tags: support, broken-link

On all the sites I've checked (Stack Overflow, Programmers, Web Applications) the "recently imported questions" link on the tools menu is pointing at:

```
/tools?tab=stats
```

But there's no list of recently imported questions on that page - that I can see. The old link of:

```
/tools/recently-imported
```

gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: recently imported, shown on the stats tab]

Comment: D'oh - how did I miss that?

Comment: I'm hoping that is rhetorical....

Comment: Of course it is.